# Nome de cidade e estado com hífen

Tags: ortografia, hífen

Corretor ortográfico do `LibreOffice` aceita nome cidade e estado usando hífen sem espaçamento entre as palavras exemplo: Afonso-MT.

Pesquisando na "internet" somente encontrei frases usando o hífen com espaçamento exemplo: Afonso - MT.

Nesse caso será que o dicionário do `LibreOffice` está incorreto?

Comment: Esse é um daqueles casos que eu vou contra as normas e coloco espaços porque, pessoalmente, não gosto de *tokens* "grudados" em palavras (ou outros *tokens*)

Answer (score 3):

O dicionário está correto.

De acordo com o livro [Os pecados da língua](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=Rc9SMDqHK50C&lpg=PA23&vq=h%C3%ADfen&pg=PA105#v=onepage&q=h%C3%ADfen&f=false) de Ledur e Sampaio, não se usam espaços com o hífen, e se usam com o travessão. No entanto esse uso do travessão ("Afonso — MT") [não está previsto](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travess%C3%A3o#Usos). Assim, a rigor, a opção correta seria:

- Afonso-MT.

Acredito que se poderia usar ao invés do hífen a [meia-risca](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meia-risca), mas note que ela [também não admite](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/o-uso-do-hifen-e-do-travessao/31251) espaços:

- Afonso–MT.

Mas o uso do hífen (e/ou da meia-risca) com espaços nesse uso me parece ser bastante difundido, e, pessoalmente, prefiro com espaços a sem. Entre as opções

1. Rio de Janeiro – RJ
2. Rio de Janeiro-RJ

a primeira me me parece mais clara e agradável — mas, de novo, formalmente, ao menos por hora, a segunda é a correta.

Comment: Alguns guias de estilos recomendam o uso da vírgula nesses casos, exemplo: "Campinas, SP"